# org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /f

Tags: java, acl, apache-zookeeper, digest-authentication

I am working with zookeeper 3.4.6, I'm using `acl` in order to authenticate with zookeeper server. I have my own implementation `ZooKeeperSupport`, it's a support for create, remove and verify znode. I am triying to create a `znode` using `acl`, but fail throwning `InvalidACLException` in this part of the code `zooKeeperSupport.create("/f", DATA_F);`

I'm basing this project to do it  [zookeeper-acl-sample](https://github.com/barkbay/zookeeper-acl-sample/), but I want to use `digest` auth because use `user` and `password`

**BasicMockZookeeperSecurity**

```
public class BasicMockZookeeperSecurity {

@Resource (name = "zooKeeperSupportFactory")
protected ZooKeeperSupportFactory zooKeeperSupportFactory;

public static final byte[] DATA_F = "data for znode /f".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
public static final byte[] DATA_B = "data for znode /b".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("curator-dont-log-connection-problems", "true");
    System.setProperty("zookeeper.security.user", "user");
    System.setProperty("zookeeper.security.password", "pass");
    System.setProperty("zookeeper.authProvider.1","com.e.product.fraud.common.zookeeper.security.CustomUserAuthenticationProvider");

    zooKeeperSupport = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().connectString(connectionPath).retryPolicy(retryPolicy).aclProvider(new ACLProvider()).build();
    zooKeeperSupport.create("/f", DATA_F);
    zooKeeperSupport.create("/b", DATA_B);
}
```

}

**ZookeeperSecurtyTest**

```
public class ZookeeperSecurtyTest extends BasicMockZookeeperSecurity {

@Test
public void securityTester() throws Exception {

    final CuratorFramework curatorFramework = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().connectString(connectionPath).retryPolicy(retryPolicy).aclProvider(new ACLProvider()).authorization(ZookeeperSecurityUtil.getCredentialsFromSystemProperties()).build();
    curatorFramework.getData().forPath("/f");

}

@After
public void teardown() throws Exception {
    System.clearProperty("zookeeeper.authProvider.1");
    System.clearProperty("zookeeper.security.user");
    System.clearProperty("zookeeper.security.password");
}
```

}

**ZooKeeperSupport**

```
@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
public class ZooKeeperSupport implements AutoCloseable {

private CuratorFramework curatorClient;

private Builder builder;

public ZooKeeperSupport(final Builder builder) {
    this.setBuilder(builder);
    this.curatorClient = builder.build();
}

public <T> T getData(final String path) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    return (T) curatorClient.getData().forPath(path);
}

public <T> T create(final String path, final byte[] data) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    return (T) curatorClient.create().forPath(path, data);
}

public <T> T create(final String path) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    return (T) curatorClient.create().forPath(path);
}

public <T> T delete(final String path) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    return (T) curatorClient.delete().forPath(path);
}

public boolean exists(final String path) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    final Stat stat = curatorClient.checkExists().forPath(StringUtils.trim(path));

    return stat != null ? true : false;
}

public void startConnection() {
    if (curatorClient.getState() == CuratorFrameworkState.LATENT) {
        curatorClient.start();
    }
}

public List<String> getChildrenNames(final String path) throws Exception {
    startConnection();

    return curatorClient.getChildren().forPath(path);
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    curatorClient.close();
    curatorClient = null;
}

public Builder getBuilder() {
    return builder;
}

public void setBuilder(final Builder builder) {
    this.builder = builder;
}

public CuratorFramework getCuratorClient() {
    return curatorClient;
}

public void setCuratorClient(final CuratorFramework curatorClient) {
    this.curatorClient = curatorClient;
}
```

}

**ZookeeperSecurityUtil**

```
public class ZookeeperSecurityUtil {

public static List<AuthInfo> getCredentialsFromSystemProperties() {
    final List<AuthInfo> authInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    final String user = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.user");
    final String password = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.password");

    authInfo.add(new AuthInfo("digest", new String(user + ":" + password).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));

    return authInfo;

}
}
```

**CustomUserAuthenticationProvider**

```
public class CustomUserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public String getScheme() {
    return "digest";
}

@Override
public Code handleAuthentication(final ServerCnxn cnxn, final byte[] authData) {
    final String userName = new String(authData, Charsets.UTF_8);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userName)) {
        cnxn.addAuthInfo(new Id(getScheme(), userName));
        return Code.OK;
    }
    return Code.AUTHFAILED;
}

@Override
public boolean isAuthenticated() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(final String arg0) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean matches(final String id, final String aclExpr) {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(id) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(aclExpr)) {
        return false;
    }
    return id.charAt(0) == aclExpr.charAt(0);
}

}
```

**ACLProvider**

```
public class ACLProvider implements org.apache.curator.framework.api.ACLProvider {

@Override
public List<ACL> getAclForPath(final String path) {

    final String firstLetter = String.valueOf(path.charAt(1));
    final Id FIRST_USER_LETTER = new Id("digest", firstLetter);

    final ACL acl = new ACL(Perms.ALL, FIRST_USER_LETTER);
    return Collections.singletonList(acl);
}

@Override
public List<ACL> getDefaultAcl() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

}
```

**Stack**

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /f
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:121)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:696)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:679)
at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:676)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:453)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:443)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:44)
at com.equifax.product.fraud.common.zookeeper.support.ZooKeeperSupport.create(ZooKeeperSupport.java:35)
at com.equifax.product.fraud.common.zookeeper.authentication.BasicMockZookeeperSecurity.setup(BasicMockZookeeperSecurity.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: did you find solution for this problem ?

Comment: @user5520049 yes I did :D

Comment: can you please illustartate how did you solve it ?

Comment: @user5520049 I have added the solution, let me know if you need more help

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  The problem with me was in RAM because of GC overhead so I increased my ram to solve the problem . thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Basically the problem is the way to create the user with password using `digest` schemee. According to zookeeper documentation, digest auth use an ID and password in base64 encode SHA1, apparently ACL doesn't make that automatically when you add the use to ACL so I had to do by myself.

```
public class ZookeeperSecurityUtil {

private static final String SHA1 = "SHA1";
private static final String COLON = ":";
private static final String DIGEST_SCHEME = "digest";

public static List<AuthInfo> getCredentialsFromSystemProperties() {
    final List<AuthInfo> authInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    final String user = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.user");
    final String password = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.password");

    authInfo.add(new AuthInfo(DIGEST_SCHEME, new String(user + COLON + password).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));

    return authInfo;
}
public static String generateDigest(final String idPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final String parts[] = idPassword.split(COLON, 2);
    final byte digest[] = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1).digest(idPassword.getBytes());
    return parts[0] + COLON + base64Encode(digest);
}
private static String base64Encode(final byte byteDigest[]) {

    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteDigest));
}
}
```

and

```
public class ACLProvider implements org.apache.curator.framework.api.ACLProvider {

private static final String ZK_DIGEST_SCHEME = "digest";

@Override
public List<ACL> getAclForPath(final String path) {

    final String user = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.user");
    final String password = System.getProperty("zookeeper.security.password");

    Id zkId = null;
    try {
        zkId = new Id(ZK_DIGEST_SCHEME, ZookeeperSecurityUtil.generateDigest(user + ":" + password));
    } catch(final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final ACL acl = new ACL(Perms.ALL, zkId);
    return Collections.singletonList(acl);
}

@Override
public List<ACL> getDefaultAcl() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

}
```