# Zookeeper based application throwing ACL exception when trying to run on Jboss

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, apache-zookeeper

```
JBoss Version : Wildfly 10
Kafka Version : 10.1.1
```

I am running basic producer , consumer application on JBoss. Initally I got error

```
"Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: File jar:file:/Users/ratha/projects/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar!/auth.confcannot be read."
```

After that searching on stack overflow I used [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761018/jboss-gives-org-apache-kafka-common-kafkaexception-auth-conf-cannot-be-read#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761018/jboss-gives-org-apache-kafka-common-kafkaexception-auth-conf-cannot-be-read)

Now I am getting ACL Exception

```
00:44:09,106 INFO  [kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) [transactioneventconsumer_ip-172-31-12-90.us-west-2.compute.internal-1497933848284-89131e85], exception during rebalance : org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$InvalidACLException: KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/transactioneventconsumer/owners/transaction_event_data/0
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException.create(ZkException.java:68)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:1000)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.create(ZkClient.java:527)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.createEphemeral(ZkClient.java:570)
    at kafka.utils.ZkPath$.createEphemeral(ZkUtils.scala:970)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.createEphemeralPath(ZkUtils.scala:446)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.createEphemeralPathExpectConflict(ZkUtils.scala:460)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$18.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:849)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$18.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:843)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.reflectPartitionOwnershipDecision(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:843)
```

Comment: did you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584568/org-apache-zookeeper-keeperexceptioninvalidaclexception-keepererrorcode-inva

Comment: Yes but don't know how to integrate this? where to add user and pass? In tomcat everything works fine.

Comment: This might help.
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch05.html